# Take the File object on upload with only one property in React jS

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to upload a file to the server, and I get this File Object with many other properties inside, what I want to do is keep the File and also inside it only the name property, I don't want the size and other properties.

Here is my JSX:

```
<input type="file" id="l-quiz-name" name="thumbnail" placeholder="Quiz Name" onChange={(e) => {
     let file = e.target.files[0];
     let newData = { ...quiz };
     newData["thumbnail"] = file;
     setQuiz(newData);
}} />
```

And here is the object:

[image: Obejt File]

And finally here is the object/state:

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        difficulty: 1,
        thumbnail: '',
        category: '61a49f18da82d9000993e281',
        questions: [],
    })
```

Comment: In which array you save the object? In `newData`?

Comment: @Giacomo in a React state named Quiz, but that is working correctly, and saving into it, what I don't know to do is how to take the File object only and the name property inside it

Comment: @Giacomo I've added the state now